# JPA/Hibernate one-to-many association modeled as one-to-one

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, domain-model

I am trying to use the effective record date pattern to simplify
the domain model.

Person to Address is OneToMany, but as of a given date it
is OneToOne.

Both Person and Address have a start and end date to account for changes over time.
In addition, Address can be used in two roles - home and work.

I am using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.2 extensions.

Therefore, I would like the domain objects to look like this:

**Person class**

```
public class Person {
@Transient
Date effectiveDate; // used to filter Person and Address record by effective date

long id;

Date start;

Date end;

String firstName;

String lastName;

Address home; // not Collection<Address> homeAddresses;

Address work; // not Collection<Address> workAddresses;

}
```

**and Address class**

```
public class Address {

long id;

Date start;

Date end;

String street;

String city;


String state;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to use @OneToOne  for the Person to Address association even though the tables are  in a OneToMany association?

2. How best to do this using JPA annotations? Hibernate provides @Filter, but wouldn't that still assume a OneToMany association?